# Problem with first java project with Whilebreakwithloop

Tags: java

Write a simple program that uses a break statement to end the while loop where the condition in while loop is always true.   Test the user input and if it is zero then use a break to exit or come out of the loop.

Do I need to add any value to execute the code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class WhileLoopWithBreak {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while () {
            continue;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If-else needs to be inside while as you will be breaking the loop on some condition

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;
class WhileLoopWithBreak {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while () {
        continue;
        else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }   Do you think this is fine? I am new to java.Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Have a look here. https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_conditions.asp

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
int n;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        # Using string as user can enter anything.
        String text = input.nextLine();
        # Trimming the input to remove white-space characters.
        if (text.trim().equals("0")){
            break;
        }
    }
```